# Dynamically adding items to FragmentGridPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, wear-os

I'm trying to display a FragmentGridPagerAdapter with 4 entries, and when the view scrolls I want to add items to the adapter.

This is my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {

private final Context _ctx;
private HashMap<Integer, Entry> _data;

public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, HashMap<Integer, Entry> tidatals) {
    super(fm);
    _ctx = context;
    _data = data;
}

public void addEntry(Entry entry)
{
    _data.put(_data.size(), entry);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int i, int i2) {

    CardFragment fragment = CardFragment.create("Card", _data.get(i).getPrettyText());
    fragment.setCardGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    fragment.setExpansionEnabled(true);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return _data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(int i) {
    return 1;
}
```

}

And this is how I add data to the adapter in my Main Wear Activity:

```
//In onCreate: 
    _data = new HashMap<Integer, Entry>();
    _adapter = new TILPagerAdapter(this, getFragmentManager(), _data);
    _pager.setAdapter(_adapter);

//When I finally get my data:
...
// Do stuff, get datas in 'data' variable
MainWear.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 boolean firstData = _data.isEmpty();
                for(TILEntry entry : data.values())
                {
                    _adapter.addEntry(entry);
                }
                if(firstData){
                    _pager.setAdapter(_adapter);
                    switchViewToResults(); // Sets pager to visible
                }
            }
        });
```

When I add items into the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(), the adapter refreshes fine, however it crashes when I scroll towards the added pages.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:873)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(GridViewPager.java:584)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.handlePointerUp(GridViewPager.java:1990)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onTouchEvent(GridViewPager.java:1492)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1944)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2085)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1532)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2033)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8026)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3559)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3616)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5589)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5569)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5540)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5669)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xadb04d70)
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: til.wear.robineisenberg.til_wear, PID: 5808
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.populate(GridViewPager.java:873)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(GridViewPager.java:584)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.handlePointerUp(GridViewPager.java:1990)
            at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onTouchEvent(GridViewPager.java:1492)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7846)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1944)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2215)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1958)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2085)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1532)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2033)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8026)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3559)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3616)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3460)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5589)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5569)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5540)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5669)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I printed the size of _data my Adapter when getFragment is called, _data.size() is correctly worth 8 when getFragment is called.

In the log, 4 is the size of the initial adapter size. 8 is the desired size afterwards. It doesn't crash upon adding the items, but only upon scrolling through the cards towards the new items. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Indeed, this seems to be an ommission in the notifyDataSetChanged function of the adapter. I opened a bug report w/ Google, star it if you think this needs to be fixed:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73846&thanks=73846&ts=1405945122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 873 in `GridViewPager.populate()` is this:

```
    this.mRowScrollX[row] = computePageLeft(...);
```

Looks like the length of the `mRowScroll` array is fixed when setting the adapter, and not updated from `getRowCount()` when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is fired. Indeed, if you check the rest of the `GridViewPager` class, you'll see it's only assigned in the `setAdapter()` method:

```
    this.mExpectedRowCount = this.mAdapter.getRowCount();
    this.mRowScrollX = new int[this.mExpectedRowCount];
```

In short, I would think this is a bug in `GridViewPager`, which could be circumvented by calling `setAdapter()` again whenever you want to update the row or column count.

Comment: Hate that I have to do this, but this worked for me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This bug should have been fixed in the latest wearable support library 1.1, that came out with the latest Android Wear 5.0 release.

Comment: Just tried it out, it works for me here on my LG-G Watch. Thank you for the information. Just a quick question: is it normal that the bug report I submitted for this issue is not marked as "resolved"? Is there an other issue tracker that I should be posting to in this case?